# How to save&load tf.keras.Model/Layer with extended methods/properties

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to extend `tf.keras.Model` to implement invertible neural networks, and save/load this model by `tf.keras.Model.save()` & `tf.keras.models.load_model()`

Specifically, I have written two classes:

- Invertible NN class

  - subclasses `tf.keras.Model`
  - has `inverse()` method
- Coupling layer class

  - subclasses `tf.keras.layers.Layer`
  - has `inverse()` method
  - has `log_det_jacobian` property (`@property`).

The code related to this looks as below (please refer to [my github repo](https://github.com/w-shimaya/glow-tf2/tree/master/model) for the full code).

```
class SimpleRealNVP(K.Model):
    ...
    def inverse(self, inputs):
        h = inputs
        for layer in self.couplings:
            h = self.layer.inverse(h)
        return h
    ...
```

```
class AffineCoupling(L.Layer):
    ....
    @property
    def log_det_jacobian(self):
        return self._log_det_jacobian

    def inverse(self, input):
        ...
```

I just tried `tf.keras.Model.save()` and `tf.keras.load_model()`, but I got an error that said

```
...
mdl = K.models.load_model("path/to/savedmodel")
...
x_manifold = mdl.inverse(z_manifold)

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File ".\manifold.py", line 54, in <module>
#     x_manifold = mdl.inverse(z_manifold)
# AttributeError: 'SimpleRealNVP' object has no attribute 'inverse'
```

What is the appropriate way to include extended methods/properties into the SavedModel?

(I've also tried specifying `custom_objects` in `load_model()` but this didn't work.)